# UIStackView and subview size classes

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have a UIStackView where the middle button is only visible in a different size class
[storyboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDeT8.png)

After rotating the device the button will be visible because of its size class and is also in the right view hierarchy (image), but is has not enough constraints given by UIstackview to be positioned correctly, it is positioned on the upper left corner (label middle).

[not enough constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd7DC.png)

The working buttons (not affected by size class changes) have much more constraints.

Is this a bug or am I missing something.
Does anybody know a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely a bug in iOS. When the middle button is installed, it's being added as a subview of the stack view, but not as an *arranged* subview.

Here's a workaround. Set the custom class of the middle button to `StackViewBugFixButton`. Then connect the (new) `priorView` outlet of the middle button to the next button to the left. Here's the definition of `StackViewBugFixButton`:

#### StackViewBugFixButton.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface StackViewBugFixButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *priorSibling;

@end
```

#### StackViewBugFixButton.m

```
#import "StackViewBugFixButton.h"

@implementation StackViewBugFixButton

- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    [super didMoveToSuperview];
    [self putIntoArrangedSubviewsIfNeeded];
}

- (void)putIntoArrangedSubviewsIfNeeded {
    if (![self.superview isKindOfClass:[UIStackView class]]) {
        return;
    }

    if (self.priorSibling == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %s You forgot to hook up my priorSibling outlet.", self, __func__);
        return;
    }

    UIStackView *stackView = (UIStackView *)self.superview;
    if ([stackView.arrangedSubviews indexOfObject:self] != NSNotFound) {
        return;
    }

    NSUInteger priorSiblingIndex = [stackView.arrangedSubviews indexOfObject:self.priorSibling];
    if (priorSiblingIndex == NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %s My priorSibling isn't in my superview's arrangedSubviews.", self, __func__);
        return;
    }

    [stackView insertArrangedSubview:self atIndex:priorSiblingIndex + 1];
}

@end
```

You'll get one spurious warning of “You forgot to hook up my priorSibling outlet” because the view gets added as a subview of the stack view during loading, before its outlets have been connected.

Comment: great, this worked perfectly, I changed it a little bit, because I don't like the outlet and drag drop but in essence its your solution, I will post it as answer to my own question

Answer (score 2):

Solutions offered by Rob and Uwe definitely work and address the issue of the conditionally-installed views not being added to `arrangedSubviews` on trait collection changes.

I preferred to address the issue without having to subclass every view that I wished to place inside a `UIStackView` though, so I subclassed `UIStackView` itself to override `layoutSubviews()` and add the orphaned subviews to `arrangedSubviews`:

```
class ManagedStackView: UIStackView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let unarrangedSubviews = subviews.filter({ !arrangedSubviews.contains($0) })
        unarrangedSubviews.forEach({ insertArrangedSubview($0, atIndex: $0._arrangedSubviewIndex) })
    }

}


extension UIView {

    private var _arrangedSubviewIndex: Int {
        get {
            return tag
        }
        set {
            tag = newValue
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rob I created the following solution with swift, you have to set controlIndex in user defined runtime values however to the right index
([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmyN6.png))

```
import UIKit

class UIButtonFixForStackView: UIButton {

    var controlIndex:Int = 0

    internal override func didMoveToSuperview() {


    if (superview?.isKindOfClass(UIStackView) == false)
    {
        return
    }

    if let stackView = self.superview as? UIStackView
    {
        if stackView.arrangedSubviews.indexOf(self) != nil
        {
            return
        }

        stackView.insertArrangedSubview(self, atIndex: controlIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answers should work as a programmatic approach, it is worth noting that you can avoid this problem in Interface Builder by adding your size class variations for the **Hidden** property instead of the **Installed** property. iOS correctly handles this scenario because the `arrangedSubviews` never actually change, and `UIStackView` is [built to adapt its layout when (arranged) subviews are hidden](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview#1653153).

For example, if you want to hide a specific view for Compact widths, the subview's IB configuration would look like the following. Note that the view is **Installed** in *all* size classes:

[image: varying the "Hidden" property]